# Prolog and lists issue

Tags: list, prolog

I have a problem with a small program that i made. Below is the part with the problem.

```
failed(X, C, Y) :- 
       registered_for(
            student(id(X),_,_,_,_,_),  
            course(name(C),year(Y),_),absences(A)), 
       A>2.

failed(X, C, Y) :- 
       grades(
            course(name(C),year(Y),_),
            student(id(X),_,_,_,_,_),_,normal(G),_,_), 
       G<5.

 count_failed(X, C, Y, N) :- 
       failed(X, C, Y), 
       append(L, C, L), 
       length(_,L,N).
```

The first 2 lines are working as intended. The problem is somewhere in the last. I want to add C on the list L but all i get is "ERROR : Out of global stack". I am using SWI-prolog.

If needed i can post the rest of the code. Thanks in advance for your time and effort :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you use `findall` to assemble the list?
The reason for the stackoverflow is probably append(L, C, L), since L  is never unified to anything inside this clause.

Comment: Also append is used for appending lists - `append(L, C, L) would mean: I want all solutions where adding C to the List leaves it unchanged.

Comment: yeah, you might want to read up on list construction, its very fundamental to prolog, and you wouldn't need any functions like append or findall to achieve it.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, you should add the homework tag :)

Comment: findall works perfectly. Thank u very very much for your time and help :)

Comment: nice. you can mark my answer as the solution to your question ... happy coding and welcome to stackoverflow!